# AggregateResult Use Case Best Practice

Tags: bestpractice, aggregate

Trying to determine best scenarios for using AggregateResult

e.g.  Versus using a for loop gathering totals with += or similar syntax.

Comment: I'm actually going to post something about this on my blog in the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: Awesome! looking forward to it, didn't find much existing content out there on the topic

Comment: @sfdcfox can you also include some best practices for using aggregateresults in batch apex? e.g. rowlimits and querylocator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AggregateResult when possible. It *always* performs *at least* as well as manual loops. The more rows you need to process, the more you'll save in CPU time.